# logical operators in data.table with by-groups

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply a logical operator to columns of data.table, which works fine without by= groups, but with by= groups something weird is happening. I'm using R 3.3.1 and data.table 1.9.6 (off CRAN).

Here is an example data set:

```
library(data.table)
# x <- matrix(rnorm(10),ncol=2)
x <- structure(c(0.323618333400921, -0.103619160085676, -0.823322722581548, 
-0.0175726272468397, 2.17286179204364, 1.63465793636681, 0.258469984285221, 
-0.411622451584, 0.22594247704226, 0.114427086028551), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))

dt <- data.table(x)
dt$id <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
dt

##             V1         V2 id
## 1:  0.32361833  1.6346579  1
## 2: -0.10361916  0.2584700  1
## 3: -0.82332272 -0.4116225  1
## 4: -0.01757263  0.2259425  2
## 5:  2.17286179  0.1144271  2
```

Let's say I would like to know if cumulative minimum (that is, the minimal value in each column either from the start of sample to current row, or from the start of the by= group to the current row) is below zero. When there are no by= groups, we are good:

```
dt[, cummin(.SD), .SDcols=1:2]
##            V1         V2
## 1:  0.3236183  1.6346579
## 2: -0.1036192  0.2584700
## 3: -0.8233227 -0.4116225
## 4: -0.8233227 -0.4116225
## 5: -0.8233227 -0.4116225

> dt[, cummin(.SD)<0, .SDcols=1:2]
##         V1    V2
## [1,] FALSE FALSE
## [2,]  TRUE FALSE
## [3,]  TRUE  TRUE
## [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
## [5,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

So far so good. I can also compute actual cumulative minimums with by= groups:

```
dt[, cummin(.SD), by=id]
##    id          V1         V2
## 1:  1  0.32361833  1.6346579
## 2:  1 -0.10361916  0.2584700
## 3:  1 -0.82332272 -0.4116225
## 4:  2 -0.01757263  0.2259425
## 5:  2 -0.01757263  0.1144271
```

However, if I try to compute the indicator variables as before, the output is as follows:

```
dt[, (cummin(.SD)<0), by=id]
##     id    V1
##  1:  1 FALSE
##  2:  1  TRUE
##  3:  1  TRUE
##  4:  1 FALSE
##  5:  1 FALSE
##  6:  1  TRUE
##  7:  2  TRUE
##  8:  2  TRUE
##  9:  2 FALSE
## 10:  2 FALSE
```

Instead of 2 variables of 5 obs. each, we have one with 10. It appears that within each by-group, the variables are stacked on top of each other. How should I do this correctly?

Comment: You might want to try this syntax : `dt[, .(cummin(V1)<0,cummin(V2)<0), by=id]`

Comment: Thanks! That works. Unfortunately in the actual application, I have a few thousand of these columns, so I'm not sure what would be a practical way to deal with that...

Comment: My guess is that `cummin` has a `data.frame` method, hence just (`cummin(dt)` works for your first attempt), while  `(cummin(.SD)<0)` is a matrix (which is just a vector) and hence while being parsed by group, `data.table` treats it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with `lapply`:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) cummin(x)<0),by="id"]
   id    V1    V2
1:  1 FALSE FALSE
2:  1  TRUE FALSE
3:  1  TRUE  TRUE
4:  2  TRUE FALSE
5:  2  TRUE FALSE
```

As commented by David Arenburg, it seems that it works with `cummin(.SD)` because it is a data.frame and it doesn't work with `cummin(.SD)<0` which is a matrix. So another solution is to cast the matrix as a data.frame :

```
dt[, (as.data.frame(cummin(.SD)<0)), by=id]
   id    V1    V2
1:  1 FALSE FALSE
2:  1  TRUE FALSE
3:  1  TRUE  TRUE
4:  2  TRUE FALSE
5:  2  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Also (without anonymous functions) ```dt[, lapply(cummin(.SD), `<`, 0), by = id]``` (though using `lapply` on `.SD` is better than just `cummin(.SD)` because it avoids matrix conversions)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
dt2 <- dt[, cummin(.SD), by = id]
results <- data.table(dt2[, .SD<0])
results$id <- dt$id

results
   id    V1    V2
1:  1 FALSE FALSE
2:  1  TRUE FALSE
3:  1  TRUE  TRUE
4:  2  TRUE FALSE
5:  2  TRUE FALSE
```